# Тихое обновление программы

Tags: delphi

Как можно осуществить тихое обновление программы, то есть без участия пользователя и т.д. только вопрос обновить или нет. сам инсталлятор скачивать глупо, то есть как можно сделать именно обновление программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у меня тот же принцип с exe в базе, я скачиваю его, кладу рядом с прогой, именуя его как-нить типа upd.exe и перед тем как завершить прогу делаю батник который пытается заменить текущий файл на обновленный и запускаю в фоне:

```
BatFile := changefileext(Application.ExeName, '.bat');
assignFile(f, BatFile);
rewrite(f);
writeln(f, ':1');
writeln(f, 'erase '+ExtractShortPathName(Application.ExeName));
writeln(f, 'if exist '+ExtractShortPathName(Application.ExeName)+' Goto 1');
writeln(f, 'rename '+ExtractShortPathName(ApplicationPath)+'upd.exe '+ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName));
writeln(f, 'start '+ExtractShortPathName(Application.ExeName)+RestartParam);
writeln(f, 'erase '+ExtractShortPathName(ApplicationPath)+'Upd.exe');
writeln(f, 'erase '+ExtractShortPathName(BatFile));
closefile(f);
ShellExecute(FMain.Handle, 'Open', PChar(BatFile), nil, nil, sw_hide);
```

и update проходит тихо и незаметно, profit

Answer (score 0):

После того как Вы проверили наличие обновлений (например сравнили версии) и начинаете скачивать файлы программы в саму программу (с заменой короче)- но это актуально только если  программа не сильно большая - 5-15 файлов...

Код уже напишите сами.

Это можно реализовать через IdFTP.

Comment: Нет у меня делается так, базе FireBird в Blob-поле будет храниться exe или инсталяторщик. проверяет версию а далее скачивает с базы и ставит.

Comment: > в Blob-поле будет храниться exe или инсталяторщик.

Не самая лучшая идея, как мне кажется. Что мешает хранить их в файловой системе?

Comment: > начинаете скачивать файлы программы в саму программу (с заменой короче)
Тут важный момент: служба обновлений должна быть независимым процессом. То есть проверяем обновления, если обновления есть, запускаем службу обновлений, выключаемся. Служба обновлений выкачивает апдейт, заменяет файлы и по окончании запускает программу.

Answer (score 0):

Я свои обновления тоже храню в базе. Удобно, если база полностью доступна, а сам сервер - нет. И еще >50 рабочих станций в локальной сети. Запаришся бегать и обновлять.

Принцип следующий:

- Делается dll-ка для запуска через `Rundll32`, чтобы обновление можно было запускать из программы (при запуске, по таймеру, через меню и т.п.), но, при этом, чтобы оно работало отдельным процессом.
- На стороне базы-данных создаем таблицу, где будут лежать файлы и информация о них (имя, блоб с самим файлом, версия, MD5-сумма)
- Регистрируем системное сообщение для обмена инфой с программой (например: `WM_AUTOUPDATE`)
- При запуске обновления, dll-ка читает список файлов в базе с файлами на клиенте и сверяет их
- Если проверяется необходимость обновить `exe` или `dll`, то сверяем версии, а, затем, MD5-суммы
- Если файлы какого-то другого формата, то, просто - MD5-суммы
- Таким образом получаем список того, что нужно обновить
- По этому списку качаем новые версии файлов из базы в `TEMP` винды
- После того как файлы скачаны, через `PostMessage` шлем бродкаст всем запущенным копиям своей программы
- Программа на это сообщение должна отреагировать диалогом с вопросом типа "Обновляемся сейчас или потом?"
- А в это время, процесс обновления начинает циклические попытки перезаписать файлы программы (тут важно установить задержку между попытками чтобы не нагружать систему)
- Если пользователь в ответ на диалог нажал "Сейчас", то программа закрывается и exe-шник заменяется очередной итерацией перезаписи
- Если - "Потом", то цикл попыток перезаписи продолжается пока программа не будет закрыта.
- Отдельная ситуация если нужно обновить саму обновляющую dll-ку. Тут нужно чтобы  она сама создала cmd-файл который ее, заменит и самоудалится, и запустила его.

Вот, в принципе, и все. В итоге получаем безвариантную систему автоматического обновления.

Для наглядности, можно передавать прогресс обновления в программу через `WM_AUTOUPDATE`.

Comment: В принципе я тоже самое сделал просто немного другая реализация)))Мысли сходятся)))

Answer (score 0):

Я переменяю следующую схему обновления. На серваке хранится версии программы там название папки это версия проги в ней лежит exe-файл который обновляем. Доступ можно получить по 80 порту. Есть специальная таблица в базе на MySql где для каждого обновляемого файла хранится версия текущая, путь к программе и md5-хэш скачиваемого файла.
Запускается программа она проверяет версию текущего файла, который лежит рядом. Если нужно то получает с сервера откуда качать и md5-хэш файла. Старую версию просто пока бэкапим. Скачался файл сразу проверяем его на целостность с помощью сравнивания md5-хэша. Все нормально удаляем бэкап, и запускаем прогу. Не все нормально удаляем скачанный файл, бэкап возвращаем наместо, а в лог в базе пишем что не удалось обновиться. Если интересно схема подробние расмотрена в статье http://myshinobi.ru/kak-sdelat-obnovlenie-programmy-na-delphi/ . Есть примеры кода.

Answer (score -1):

Есть готовый компонент, который все сделает за вас - [TMS TWebUpdate](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/wupdate.asp).

Comment: И всё не то. До ужаса просто надо сделать. само обновление можно по сути сделать в этой же программе которая просто будет скачивать допустим архив с программой и распаковывать её в папку.
Только как работать с архивами в Дельфи